# Defining a recursive sequence of ratios given another sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $[f_n]$ is defined recursively by $f_1=1, f_2=1$, and $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$, for $n≥3$.

Define the sequence $[r_n]$ of ratios by setting: $r_n=\frac {f_{n+1}} {f_n}, n≥1$.

I'm having trouble using the definition of the sequence $[f_n]$ to give a recursive definition of the sequence $[r_n]$. So far I have that:

$[r_n]=1, 2, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{8}{5}, \frac{13}{8}, \frac{21}{13}, \frac{34}{21}\dots$ I know that I need to find a formula for $r_n$ in terms of $r_{n-1}$ etc, but I'm not seeing any relation between the numbers other than the numerator switches to the denominator with each succession. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, for $n \gt 1$,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
r_n & = \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} \\
& = \frac{f_n + f_{n-1}}{f_n} \\
& = 1 + \frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n} \\
& = 1 + \frac{1}{\left(\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n-1}}\right)} \\
& = 1 + \frac{1}{r_{n-1}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: Thank you for editing for extra clarity in the formula!

Comment: @djde You're welcome. I strive to make my answers clear & relatively easy to follow, even if sometimes it makes them longer than they really need to be.

Comment: I'm now trying to find the limit of the sequence, given that $[r_n]$ converges to limit R. The only thing I can think of is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac{1}{r_{n-1}}=1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{r_{n-1}}=1+\frac{1}{R}=R$, and then solve for R? It seems logically flawed but not sure where else to go from there. @John Omielan

Comment: @djde As long as the sequence *does* converge, your method of finding the limit does work. If you use what you started with of $1 + \frac{1}{R} = R$, you'll get $2$ roots, of which only one is valid. In particular, it'll be the "golden ratio" $\varphi$. Note the sequence $f_n$ is the Fibonacci one, with your ratio limit being studied & determined by Johannes Kepler, as discussed in the [Limit of consecutive quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients) section of Wikipedia's "Fibonacci number" article.

Answer (score 1):

Different algebra:

$f_nr_n=f_{n+1}$;

$f_{n+1}r_{n+1}=f_{n+2}$;

Subtracting:

$f_{n+1}r_{n+1}-f_nr_n=f_n$;

Dividing by $f_n:$

$r_nr_{n+1}-r_n=1$;

$r_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{r_n}.$